# Can I recover pictures from waterlogged phone?

Tags: iphone, damage

So, my iPhone 6 fell in a pool and will not turn on. I tried plugging it in but somehow the charger port (like where you plug the charger in) is deformed or something because the charger will only go in about halfway. I'm sure this makes the usual methods of data recovery a bit more complicated. Is it possible to still recover my photos?

Comment: Did you really plug it in after pulling it out of the pool? Or did you give it some time to dry?

Comment: My guess is you didn't sync pictures to your computer of over iCloud Photos or Google Photos or anything like that, otherwise you wouldn't be asking this. Let your phone dry for a day. Then try holding the power and home buttons for about 10 seconds. Also try a different lightning cable, it's hard to think that water would change the shape of the phone. If you can get it to boot but not connect to a cord, you can sync over WiFi. Other thoughts: Did you have an iCloud backup or use photo stream?

Comment: @sekdiy i let it dry in rice for a day but no luck

Comment: @kal-al no i didn't use iCloud for my pictures unfortunately

Answer (score 1):

First consider ofcourse if you have any backups on your computer, in iCloud or other cloud services.

If not, and you're not able to fix the defective port by yourself, you can use a data recovery service. They might be able to retrieve the photos.

In the past I have successfully used IBAS / Kroll Ontrack data recovery services to recover data from an iPhone with a similar problem. However, note that it is guaranteed that it will work - and there might be complications if your data is encrypted, etc. However, they are able to provide an analysis for a limited fee, so that you know before paying the full fee, how likely it is for you to get all your data back.

Their homepage is here:

http://www.krollontrack.co.uk

I cannot see from your profile where you are located, but they operate in many different countries.